# jQuery - Keyup Restriction - No more characters after percentage sign

Tags: jquery

I've written a jQuery "keypress" function that is supposed to facilitate the input of numbers and percentages within certain text inputs.

It looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
"use strict";
$('body').on('keypress', '[data-input-restriction="percentage"]', function(event) {

    // Allow only backspace and delete
    if ( event.which == 46 || event.which == 8 || event.which == 37) {
        // continue
    } else {
        // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
        if (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57) {
            event.preventDefault(); 
        }   
    }
    // allow no more typing after first %
    if(($(this).val().toString().split("%").length - 1) > 0) {
            event.preventDefault(); 
    }
});
});
```

Now, as you can see, the function only allows Numbers (`0-9`), Dots (`.`) and Percentage Symbols (`%`).

Also, currently the function prohibits **any typing** once the first Percentage Sign has been entered. What I'm trying to figure out is how to change that if-statement in order to prohibit **any typing AFTER** the first percentage sign (in order to keep the user from entering a value like `10%9`, and at the same time allowing the user to edit an existing percentage value).

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: When you mean "any typing", do you also mean characters that aren't numbers? So you can basically do `50% GGFF`?

Comment: If i understand you correctly then this is a validation issue. You can do this in many diffirent ways. The easiest way I think and a very useful language for validation is regular expressions. 
http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: Mortimer: Make sure you also check if `this.selectionStart == $(this).val().length` before you can insert the percentage sign, otherwise you can enter a bunch of numbers then go back and enter the sign in the middle of the sentence.

Comment: @Snorlax: would you simply add `&& this.selectionStart == $(this).val().length` to the first if-statement? This does not seem to work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the caret position and then check if the previous character is a `%` then prevent default.

You can find the location of the caret in a text box by **`this.selectionStart`**

Please check the snippet below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  "use strict";
  $('body').on('keypress', 'input', function(event) {
    // allow no more typing after first %
    if(this.selectionStart>0 && $(this).val().charAt(this.selectionStart-1)=='%'){
       event.preventDefault(); 
    }
    // Allow only backspace and delete
    if ( event.which == 46 || event.which == 8 || event.which == 37) {
      // continue
    } else {
      // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
      if (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57) {
        event.preventDefault(); 
      }   
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <input type=text />
</body>
```

Comment: Wow, that's amazing! Thank you very much, great approach.

Comment: Damn, this is better than mine: http://jsfiddle.net/2ghoeqrc/2/ - Oh well, there's another approach :P

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the last char is the `%` and the caret position in order to permit changes.

Code:

```
if ($(this).val().substr($(this).val().length - 1) == '%' && this.selectionStart >= $(this).val().length) {
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/79fbknwL/